# textfield, table view and tableview cell default background colour is black

Tags: xcode, background, storyboard, textfield, default

Not sure if this is a bug with xcode 12+ I'm using xcode 14.3.1
Seems to relate to the link below, difference being, I want to see the placeholder text with a white background
[Since Xcode 12 uitextfields of existing project has black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64060233/since-xcode-12-uitextfields-of-existing-project-has-black-background?rq=3)

For some reason the background default colour on the view controller is called 'system background' in the attribute inspector, but shows as black in the iOS stimulator and the placeholder text light grey.

I can change the background default colour to white for the textField, tableView and tableViewCell, but shouldn't it be white by default?

My issue is:

If I change the background to white the placeholder text is no longer visible.

I tried creating a new project and just drag and drop a text field in the main view controller, run the project and everything is black.

My problem is the placeholder text doesn't show up when I change the textfield background to white as it is light grey.

When I change the default textfield colour to white the textfield placeholder text "I should be able to read this with a white background but can't" can't be seen.

If I can solve the textfield problem I can solve the table view and tableview cell default colour being black problem too.

[The default black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMWYZ.jpg)
[I should be able to read this with a white background but can't][1]

I want to see the placeholder text with a white background, in the iOS stimulator by default it's black(called: system background white box in the attribute inspector) even if i change colours programmically to white the placeholder text is light grey and invisible.

I can change the textField background to white but then I can no longer see the too faint to read placeholder text

EDIT****

[Xcode seems to have fixed itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfI6m.png)

Comment: Is this happening with.a new project, or an existing project that you had upgraded?

Comment: For some of my older projects, I found stray colors in the code that weren't semantic colors and storyboards that appeared to hard color choices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @benc It’s happening for both and the above is for a brand new project. 

It’s happening by default with the default color or system color that has been selected by default

Comment: You might be using fixed (normal) colors, and be working with some Apple defaults that are adaptive. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/appearance_customization/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface#2993897
If you are going to change the colors, you probably have to set them all yourself. Like `.systemWhite` for the background, then `.systemBlack` for the text.

Comment: This happens with a brand new project, out of the box, after dropping a textfield in the view and running the ios stimulator the text field is black and text is white. That means if I change the text field colour to white manually via the attribute inspector or code the placeholder text is invisible as it retains the same light grey colour that was visible ontop of the black background that i get for some reason by defualt but inviisble if i change the textfeilds background to white. Hope this makes sense, thanks ben

Comment: @B.O.M.B - did you turn on **Dark Appearance** on your simulator?

Comment: For some reason, it seems to have fixed itself now. I can see the placeholder text in the stimulator now, with its white background.